# How to enable CORS on endpoints that don't require authorization

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors

I have a a Springboot endpoint that is being called from a fronted app. Whenever I try to get or post data I end up with an error

> XMLHttpRequest error.

I have setup CORS support for endpoints that require authorization and they work well no errors. How can I set up CORS for endpoints that don't require authorization?

What I have done so far

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements Filter, WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        System.out.println("WebConfig; "+request.getRequestURI());
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With,observe");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "responseType");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "observe");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        System.out.println("Request Method: "+request.getMethod());
        if (!(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS"))) {
            try {
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Pre-flight");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,DELETE,PUT");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Expose-Headers"+"Authorization, content-type," +
                    "USERID"+"ROLE"+
                    "access-control-request-headers,access-control-request-method,accept,origin,authorization,x-requested-with,responseType,observe");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }

    }

}
```

my controller that doesn't require authorization

```
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/web")
@RestController
public class WebOptionController {
```

this is my webconfigsecurity

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/reset_password").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/web/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```